# How to print my string argument as a tuple

Tags: python, string, if-statement, tuples

So currently my output is:

[image]

It's returning it as a string however I want it to return with a tuple with 5 items.

The lastname and other names being a different area
when I use return(tuple(lecturerinfo)) it gives me:

[image]

Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
def part1(lecturerinfo):
    return (lecturerinfo)

part1_list = input('please enter employ information')
mytup = ()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    mytup = part1(part1_list)
    print(mytup)
```

Comment: Not 6 items? Your string is whitespace delimited and will produce 5 items. Or, are you trying to get some of the fields together?

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.split()` to split the fields into a list of separate strings. Then convert the list to a tuple:

```
>>> '21345 CSEE 21000 James Frank Smith'.split()
['21345', 'CSEE', '21000', 'James', 'Frank', 'Smith']
>>> t = tuple('21345 CSEE 21000 James Frank Smith'.split())
>>> t
('21345', 'CSEE', '21000', 'James', 'Frank', 'Smith')
```

Now you have a tuple with 6 items. I'm not sure how you will handle splitting of the first name(s) and surname, but this should point you in the right direction.